# Inconsistency in definition of characteristics for a linear PDE? Folland versus Fritz John.

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

There seems to be a major inconsistency (perhaps due to my lack of understanding) between what Folland calls a "characteristic" and what I had previously thought was a characteristic.

For example, Folland says that the characteristics of the equation $\partial_x u = 0$ are $\{ \xi : \xi_1 = 0\}$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$). This confuses me to no end since I thought the characteristic hypersurface was the $x_1$ axis here? According to this definition it's the orthogonal compliment to this. The same issue arises with the heat operator $L=u_t-u_{xx}$ where he says the characteristics are $\{\xi \neq 0 : \xi_x = 0\}$. Aren't the characteristics $t=$ cosntant which are orthogonal to these?

Sorry if this question is elementary but it's given me a real headache and I'm not sure what it is I'm missing here.

Comment: You're confusing the so-called "characteristic variety", which is the set of all $\xi$ where the symbol vanishes and lives in the cotangent fiber, and a "characteristic hypersurface", which is a hypersurface in the domain of the PDE such that its conormal cotangent vector (known classically as the normal vector) at each point lies inside the characteristic variety. In other words, a hypersurface is characteristic if the symbol of the PDE vanishes when evaluated on a conormal cotangent vector.

Comment: I really don't know any geometry. Can you please translate what you said into something about surfaces in $R^2$ or $R^3$?

Comment: Dorian, it's a lot easier to explain this stuff in person than on the internet. It says on your profile that you're a grad student at Courant. Couldn't you consult a classmate or professor there? Or, if you're willing to take the A train to Brooklyn, you're welcome to drop by my office some time and ask me.

Comment: Sorry it's a Sunday and no one is around. I'll try to re-interpret what you said in more basic language and perhaps ask someone tomorrow.
Thanks.


Comment: I assume you mean Folland's "Intro to PDE" book. Take a look at the end of Section 1.A (p.34 in the second edition). "A hypersurface is called *characteristic* for $L$ at $x \in S$ if the normal vector $\nu(x)$ to $S$ at $x$ is in $\mathrm{char}_x(L)$".

Comment: Ok so he does have the same notion of characteristic hypersurface. I just wasn't used to the principal symbol characterization or whatever it is. Thanks Deane and Hans for clarifying things. 

Comment: I haven't looked at Folland or John in a long time, but I am pretty sure that if you parse what they say very carefully, you'll figure it out. It *is* confusing. I also recommend spending the time to learn the more modern language of cotangent and conormal vectors. It is also confusing at first, but makes things much clearer in the long run.

Comment: Just to add one more remark to Deane's comment: one of the reasons to consider characteristic varieties rather than characteristic surfaces is that in more than two dimensions, for variable coefficient PDEs, characteristic varieties are not necessarily integrable. So that you may have a good description of the characteristic variety _without_ having any hypersurface that realizes it. 

Comment: @Willie: are you sure about that? I thought it was a theorem by Gabber and others that the characteristic variety is integrable, which, if I'm not confused, basically means that you can find characteristic hypersurfaces.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: I may be wrong, but don't the theorems you are referring to all depend on analyticity of the coefficients? Gabber's paper I just can't understand at all, but few results he referred to (and the few others I am aware of) applied, to the best of my knowledge, only to the analytic case. (And sorry for the late response. Before MO2.0 there were no comment notifications.)

Comment: @WillieWong: I think Gabbers result requires noetherianity which is (I think) satisfied for analytic PDEs. (Btw. do you know of any important PDEs which are not analytic, or even algebraic?). Since this is some time ago I don't remember if what you meant with "integrable" is the same thing as the notion appearing in Gabbers or all the other works I've seen on characteristics.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: "Do you know any important PDEs which are not analytic, or even algebraic?" Practically anything that is quasilinear would satisfy the requirement; at least, in these cases one cannot demand a priori analyticity/algebraicity etc. It is likely though, when I wrote my comment three years ago I was thinking of something rather artificial built up by gluing together using bump functions two operators with very different characteristics.

Comment: @WillieWong: Thanks! Could you point me to places where I could see such quasilinear non-analytic PDEs and the context in which they appear?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: They are everywhere in classical mathematical physics; the questions concerning characteristics play more of a role in the evolution problem. Courant and Hilbert is a start, but you may also want to look into nonlinear elasticity and nonlinear electrodynamics.

Comment: @WillieWong: just to make sure we are talking about the same thing, do you mean the equations are non analytic or their solutions?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold: since this question concerns characteristics, I mean that the linearisation of the equation along solutions is non analytic, which is a consequence of the fact that the solutions themselves are non analytic. On the other hand, for a lot of the studies in nonlinear elasticity the equations themselves are also non-analytic.